# Python printing of Fibonacci doesn't work

Tags: python, math, cmath

I'm trying to print the Fibonacci sequence [Benet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html), however my values aren't correct. Am I missing something here?

```
import math

def F(n):
    return ((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5))

for x in range(0, 100):
    print(F(x))
```

The results i'm getting are:

```
0.0
1.0
1.0
2.0
3.0000000000000004
5.000000000000001
8.000000000000002 --- start's going wrong here
13.000000000000002
21.000000000000004
...
```

It must have something to do with **precision**. However using `cmath` instead of `math` doesn't seem to help either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Also, read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the result as an `int` if you are worried about it, that's just an artifact of how you can represent floating point numbers.

```
import math

def F(n):
    return int(((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5)))

for x in range(0, 15):
    print F(x)
```

Output

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work for lower values, however I receive an overflow error if i try to get for instance the 701th number. (sorry for my potential stupidity, i'm `c#` developer however I need to perform arbitrary precision math. Might I be on the wrong path?)

Comment: @Ropstah then use a `long` instead of `int`

Comment: I'm using version 3. According to some other post the difference between int and long was removed in python 3.x? Anyway, if I don't cast and just perform the calculation, then the results are also off... Do I need to do something special for Python to perform arbitrary precision math?

Comment: Sorry for being lazy. `mpmath` is what i need I guess :)